# Run python script on cron using conda

Tags: python, cron, conda

Trying to send some output to Slack using cron on an instance of GCP Compute Engine running Linux `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`.

Output is generated by python script.

Python script is usually run using `conda activate my_env` and `python my_script.py`

I have made the bash file executable by doing `chmod +x my_script.bash`

Here is content of bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/miniconda3/bin/activate
conda activate my_env
python /home/user/folder/cron/reports.py -r check_stocks
```

I would expect adding the following line to `crontab -e`:

`00 21 * * * cd /home/user/folder/cron/ && /bin/bash my_script.bash` would give me the same results.

I run `cd /home/user/folder/cron/ && /bin/bash my_script.bash` in my shell and the script runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make your .py file exacutable too (`chmod +x file.py`) - otherwise it won't work.
You can find similar issue resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62192532/12257250).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I gave up activating the `conda` environment and instead  called directly the python bin in the miniconda environment folder, like this:

```
00 21 * * * /home/myuser/miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin/python /home/user/folder/cron/reports.py
```

I don't think this is the recommended solution, especially if you have a complex project with dependencies and you are importing a lot of modules, but for my simple script it solved the problem.